# KeePassXC just stopped running

Tags: keepassxc

One day KeePassXC just stopped running. I click on icon, there is boot process and then nothing. I tried to start it from terminal and I get the error:

```
ERROR: not connected to the kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20 content interface.
```

What does it mean? Literally, yesterday, I could still use it.
Am I need to do something like that:

```
sudo snap connect kdenlive:kde-frameworks-5-plug kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20:kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20-slot
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolve this just by updating packages using `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

But, thanks @flaargen, also may be this will help:

```
sudo snap install kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20
```

Answer (score 2):

Launching keepassxc from the terminal I get the following error:

```
keepassxc
ERROR: not connected to the kde-frameworks-5-91-qt-5-15-3-core20 content interface.
```

My resolution was to run sudo snap install on the specific package that was reported in the error message. In my case kde-frameworks-5-***91***-qt-5-15-3-core20.

```
sudo snap install kde-frameworks-5-91-qt-5-15-3-core20
```

If you run the sudo snap install command, make sure to run it on the correct package.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue, and was able to resolve by running:

```
sudo snap install kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20
```

Clicked the KeePassXC icon again afterwards and it opened like normal.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Perhaps it really works, I think, but (I forget to write about here) I resolve this just by updating packages using "sudo apt-get update" and upgrade